# OpenVPN Connects but Unable to access hosts on another subnet

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, linux-networking

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with latest OpenVpn package. First time trying to get a vpn going myself.

Unable to ping any hosts that are currently on the 10.10.0.0
via my windows machine client.

I can ping either direction when ssh'd into any system on that subnet.

UFW is currently disabled.

OpenVPN connects fine, I am however able to ping the openvpn host address of 10.10.3.98.

/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward set to 1 on all systems

Thinking some kind of route issue, but i've tried a few things with no luck. I need the collective.

Thank-you!

host1:/etc/openvpn$ ip addr

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:2a:f5:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet PUBLICIP/32 scope global dynamic ens3
       valid_lft 70352sec preferred_lft 70352sec
    inet6 2607:5300:201:2100::fdf/56 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe2a:f5f1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:cc:88:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.3.98/16 brd 10.10.255.255 scope global dynamic ens4
       valid_lft 70352sec preferred_lft 70352sec
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fecc:88e1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.0.0.1/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::22db:5c7d:76e4:21c2/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

server.conf

```
port 1194
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_hCBOMjVqB0C2SZat.crt
key server_hCBOMjVqB0C2SZat.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

ip routes

```
ip route
default via PUBLICGWIP dev ens3 proto dhcp src PUBLICIP metric 100
10.0.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1
10.10.0.0/16 dev ens4 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.3.98
PUBLICGWIP dev ens3 proto dhcp scope link src PUBLICIP metric 100
169.254.169.254 via 10.10.0.1 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.10.3.98 metric 100
```

client config (minus keys)

```
client
proto udp
explicit-exit-notify
remote PUBLICIP 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_hCBOMjVqB0C2SZat name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
```

host2 (host I am unable to ping)

```
ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:02:6e:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet PUBLICIP/32 scope global dynamic ens3
       valid_lft 69012sec preferred_lft 69012sec
    inet6 2607:5300:201:2100::862/56 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe02:6eb7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:57:46:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.3.222/16 brd 10.10.255.255 scope global dynamic ens4
       valid_lft 69012sec preferred_lft 69012sec
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe57:4657/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


ip route
default PUBLICGWIP dev ens3 proto dhcp src PUBLICIP metric 100
10.10.0.0/16 dev ens4 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.3.222
PUBLICGWIP dev ens3 proto dhcp scope link src PUBLICIP metric 100
169.254.169.254 via 10.10.0.2 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.10.3.222 metric 100
```

Windows client ipconfig when connected to VPN

```
Unknown adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9 for OpenVPN Connect
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-0B-15-88-B7
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4719:c54f:b42e:fe72%50(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 838926091
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-28-0C-DC-F8-3C-7C-3F-F3-68-C1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

host2 has no route to reach `10.0.0.0/24`.

It needs a route for `10.0.0.0/24 via 10.10.3.98` to know that `10.10.3.98` acts as a gateway to reach `10.0.0.0/24`.

Remember that you need routes pointing in both direction.

Comment: I tried sudo ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.10.3.98 on host2 (note: I changed to 10.8* from 10.0*) and tracert still stops at 10.8.0.1 and won't ping

Comment: I got it to work by also adding the following on the vpn host:

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens4 -j MASQUERADE

Thanks for you help

Comment: Why a route to 10.8.0.0/24? That's not mentioned *anywhere* in your question.